# How to use Kmelon as eclipse web browser

Tags: eclipse

How to use Kmelon browser as Eclipse web browser? It's not present in the Eclipse browsers list under `Window/Web browser`. Is there a way to set up it via Eclipse configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actualy, it was fairly simple
`preferences - general - web browser - new`